# Returning data from php with jquery and ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, request, call

I have a problem.

I am making an Ajax request to a php file. I would like to display the result in the page, but I can't. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit_your_name").click(function() {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });

        var name = $("#your_name").val();
        var data = 'your_name=' + name;

        if(name) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                aSync: false,
                url: "1.php",
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#get_name").fadeOut();
                    $("#page_1").fadeIn();
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

And then:

```
<div id="page_1" class="page_common" style="display: none;">

<p>Hello //I want to display the name here... , what are you after?</p>
```

What can I do? Any ideas???

Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

First remove `aSync: false,` from your ajax function. You are after all doing a asynchronous call.

If nothing goes wrong, your `div` `#page_1` contains what your process file `1.php` tells it to contain. (Make sure you are `echoing` the wanted result.)